# Inputs not echoed with pipeline

Tags: shell

I wrote a program that takes inputs from shell and then outputs results. However, the input is not echoed when I use a pipeline.

```
$ ./a.out
$ /home/Wisatbff/file       # input a pathname (echoed)
```

use pipeline:

```
$ ./a.out | more
$                           # input (same as above, not echoed)
```

Both output correctly. Why the input is not echoed when using pipeline?

Comment: Could it be a difference between `stdout` and `stderr`? What's in your code?

Comment: Do you have an alias for "more"? If you alias more=less, then you might want to `export LESS=-X`

Comment: @glennjackman No. `more is /bin/more`

Comment: @EmoMosley The program opens a file and writes it to stdout.

Comment: @Wisatbff - What does `./a.out|cat` produce?

Comment: @EmoMosley Same as `./a.out` with inputs echoed.

Comment: perhaps `more` takes over stdin, thus your input goes directly to `more`? try `echo /home/Wisatbff/file | ./a.out | more`

Comment: @shx2 Nope. I also wrote a simpe program which adds two numbers. It works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT (the earlier answer was wrong, I misunderstood the question):

the command `more` is changing your terminal configuration.

Find out the tty where you are launching your `./a.out | more` and run this command from another tty (or any other therminal):

`stty -F /dev/yourTTY echo`

And you will have echo again on your console

Perhaps you are using a pseudoterminal, but `stty` command should work as well.

**For example**:

1. Find out your current terminal: `ps ax | grep $$ | awk '{ print $2 }'`
2. Run your commands: `./a.out | more`
3. Open new terminal and run this command: `stty -F /dev/resultFromFirstStep echo`
4. Check you have again echo on your first terminal.

EDIT:

By the way, if someone is interested, you can see how `more` is changing the terminal reading the [code source](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.20/util-linux-2.20.1.tar.gz):

```
void set_tty () {
    otty.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON|ECHO);
    otty.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;    /* read at least 1 char */
    otty.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;   /* no timeout */
    stty(fileno(stderr), &otty);
}
```

It is taking away ECHO and ICANON.

Comment: But why the input is not echoed?

Comment: the `more` command is changing your tty configuration. You can see your current tty configuration with the stty comand, for example: `stty -a -F /dev/YOURTTY` or just `stty -a` for your current terminal. See my edit for more information about how to renable your echo

Comment: Awesome. I thought `more` waits for input before it changes the terminal confs.